# Rewrite Rule Not Working - After Software Update

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

My users have all been sent a unique link. Example;

```
http://example.com/limeSurvey190/index.php?sid=59684&lang=en&token=1234567890
```

`token` is unique here.

I have done a LimeSurvey software update so that now my user will need to go here instead;

```
http://example.com/surveys/index.php/survey/index/sid/59684/
token/1234567890/lang/en
```

I tried this rule;

```
RewriteRule ^limeSurvey190/index.php?sid=59684&lang=en&token=([0-9]+)/?$ surveys/index.php/survey/index/sid/59684/token/$1/lang/en [NC]
```

It doesn't work. I'm pretty new to Rewrite/Redirect rules so I might have misunderstood the point of `RewriteRule`

Comment: You can't match query string in rewriterule. You need to use query_string or check the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\s/+limeSurvey190/index\.php\?sid=(59684)&lang=en&token=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /surveys/index.php/survey/index/sid/%1/token/%2/lang/en? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That didn't work either. Why is 59684 in brackets here?

Comment: Where did you put that rule? It needs to go before the other rules.